# Intel Edison IoT Edition and XDK IDE with node.js

Tags: node.js, intel-xdk, intel-edison

I went to use the Intel XDK IDE with node.js and noticed all the samples and templates assume that you are connected to a Arduino Breakout Board. I am not connected to a Arduino Breakout Board, I am using Sparkfuns GPIO block. When I run any of the sample apps, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Failed to write to export
>   Intel Edison Failed to initialise Arduino board TriState,
>   check i2c devices! FATAL

Is it possible to use the Intel XDK to develop node.js apps for the Edison without the using the Arduino Breakout Board? If so, how? If not, can you use Eclipse or any other IDE to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some tips here - https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa/blob/master/docs/edison.md  The main one is using libmraa

Answer (score 0):

Today I troubleshot this same error message.  An update to Yocto 1.6.1 solved it.  It was very strange as the code ran on my Edison with 1.6 but did not run on my friends with 1.6.  I would try upgrading if you have not solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update your version of mraa - you can do this using npm or opkg, just check the README on the mraa project - https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa.

0.6.0 or higher is recommended for using anything but the arduino breakout. I've used it on some of the sparkfun boards and it works.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, all boards have different GPIO (and other peripheral port handle) names. These are named after the SOC/SOM documentation for each supported board.

For SparkFun, you further have two options:

1. GPIO Block : you go for mraa. Ref : https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa
2. Pi Block : you can easily work on it like you do on RasPi with all i2c Ports and everything! Ref : https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/edison-sparkfun-io.html

PS : I strongly suggest using Pi Block, if you are new to IoT. Reason :  You might need the i2c bus to get readings from SDA and SCL.